# Managing buffers of binary data in C++

Tags: c++, binary, arduino, buffer

I'm trying to create a simple binary format to transmit over a BlueToothLE module on Arduino. I'm trying to describe properties of a list of objects. And for starters I'm trying to transmit just a single property.

The format I'm attempting to encode and pass around is as follows.

```
namePropertyID, nameLength, nameString...
```

So given a name of "Bob"

```
0x01     0x03     0x42 0x6F 0x62
nameID   3 chars  "B"  "o"  "b"
```

But when I pass the buffer around, it seems to mutate.

before I pass it, it reads:

```
0x01 0x03 0x42 0x6F 0x62
```

But after I pass it, it reads:

```
0x00 0x3C 0x18 0x04 0x00
```

**Program.h**

```
typedef enum {
  InfoTypeName = 0x01
} InfoType;

class Program {
  public:
    char *name;

    uint8_t * data();
    uint8_t dataLen();
};
```

**Program.cpp**

```
#include "Program.h"

uint8_t* Program::data() {
  uint8_t nameLength = strlen(name);
  uint8_t buff[dataLen()];

  buff[0] = InfoTypeName;
  buff[1] = nameLength;

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < nameLength; i++) {
    buff[i+2] = (uint8_t)name[i];
  }

  // First check of data, things look ok.
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < nameLength+2; i++) {
    Serial.print(F(" 0x")); Serial.print(buff[i], HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();

  return buff;
}

uint8_t Program::dataLen() {
  return strlen(name) + 2;
}
```

Elsewhere I pass this to the Bluetooth library:

```
BTLEserial.write(program.data(), program.dataLen());
```

Which is implemented like so, and is printing out seemingly incorrect data:

```
size_t Adafruit_BLE_UART::write(uint8_t * buffer, uint8_t len)
{
  Serial.print(F("\tWriting out to BTLE:"));
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<len; i++) {
    Serial.print(F(" 0x")); Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // actually sends the data over bluetooth here...
}
```

So a few questions:

- Why the data mutating?
- Is this a good approach for generating buffers?
- Is having two separate methods, one for length and one for data a good pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that in `Program::data()`, `buff` is a local variable. You are returning a pointer to its first element, which is a dangling pointer at the call side. You need to ensure the buffer you export is something that stays alive for long enough. There are different ways of doing this, but I am not entirely familiar with the limitations arduino places on what parts of the C and C++ standard libraries you can use.

The simplest approach could be to reserve a buffer in `main`, and pass that around to the code that populates it and consumes it. Alternatively, you could give your `Program` class a buffer data member. The main problem is going to be ensuring that the buffer is large enough for different messages.

I would first try something like this:

```
void create_msg_(const char* name, uint8_t buff, size_t size)
{
  // populate buff with the message
}

void send_msg(const char* name)
{
  size_t size = strlen(name) + 2;
  uint8_t buff[size]; // VLA extension, not std C++
  create_msg_(name, buff, size);
  BTLEserial.write(buff, size);
}
```

Comment: When I `return buff`, why wouldn't it "stick around"?

Comment: @AlexWayne Because it is local to the function, so it ceases to exist when you return.

Comment: Creating the buffer on the caller-side is actually quite a common pattern, for example `sprintf` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) and `fread` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) use it. These assume that the buffer will be big enough, if you want to be sure you could choose a solution like `snprintf` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) has where you pass in the maximum size and it returns how many characters it *would* have liked to return.

Comment: Interesting. My first attempt at prepping a buffer at the caller side failed, though. `uint8_t buff[program.dataLen()] = program.data()` yields `variable-sized object 'buff' may not be initialized`. Which means I _must_ give it a fixed size preset to the largest possible message size? Poor little Arduino only has 2.5K RAM.

Comment: @AlexWayne You have the variable-length arrays extension (not standard C++), so you can create an array of the right length, pass a pointer to its first element and a size to a `make_message` method, then send it with a `send_message` method. I don't see any need for classes here (although these may be one, there just isn't anything in your post that suggests so.)

Comment: so would you recommend he design `data()` with `bool Program::data( uint_t* ptrdata) { if( !ptrdata ) return false; ... copy buffer ... return true; }` ... and then two-step call...

`uint8_t *usidedata= new uint8_t[ program.datalen() ];`
`if( program::data(&usidedata) ) BTLEserial.write( usidedata, program.datalen() );`
`delete [] usidedata;`

or something similar? i previously forgot to declare usidedata....

Comment: Rather than play around with low level buffers, you might find you get more mileage from the standard library. For example the `uint8_t buff[]` can be replaced with `std::vector<uint8_t>` which is efficient, can be returned from a function (efficiently) and intrinsically carries the 'size' information.

Comment: For now I think the C++ std lib is out of reach, but thank you the info. This makes sense now, though I'm still wrestling with the syntax. I've settled on passing in a reference to the `BTLEserial` instance, and passing the buffer directly to it from the function that made it. So we now have `sendDescriptor()` instead of `data()`. Not as clean, but it's now working as expected. Thanks for the enlightenment!